# wait for firebase to load onsnapshot

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Got these two methods. I have a class which calls the method getFamily before this.family is assigned since onSnapshot has not finished loading. How can i restructure this so a call to getFamily will wait for onsnapshot to finish? Is it possible to use promises?

```
getFamily() {
    return this.family;
}

setFamilyID(familyID) {
    this.familyID = familyID;

    this.db.collection("families").doc(this.familyID).onSnapshot((familyDoc) => {
        console.log("family updated");

        this.family = familyDoc;
    });
}
```

Comment: i believe you want async/await

Answer (score 16, accepted):

## Realtime

If you need realtime updates, wrap the `onSnapshot` in a `Promise`. You'll need to keep a handle on the return value of `onSnapshot` so you can detach when the component is destroyed. Also, make sure to only call `resolve` once.

```
getFamily() {
  return this.family;
}

setFamilyID(familyID) {
  this.familyID = familyID;
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    var resolveOnce = (doc) => {
      resolveOnce = () => void;
      resolve(doc);
    };
    this.detachFamilyIDWatcher = this.db
      .collection("families").doc(this.familyID)
      .onSnapshot((familyDoc) => {
        console.log("family updated");

        this.family = familyDoc;
        resolveOnce(familyDoc);
      }, reject);
  });
}
```

## Just Once

If you only need to load the data once, then just use `get` instead of `onSnapshot`. `get` returns a `Promise` and doesn't require detaching.

```
getFamily() {
  return this.family;
}

setFamilyID(familyID) {
  this.familyID = familyID;

  return this.db
    .collection("families").doc(this.familyID)
    .get().then((familyDoc) => {
      console.log("family updated");

      this.family = familyDoc;
    });
}
```

Comment: Returning promise was a good idea however can you explain why you declare resolveOnce variable-function instead of just calling the newly created Promise resolve?

Comment: @TarvoMäesepp Did you figure out why they did that?