# onSnapshot firebase, getServerSideProps

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, next.js, server-side-rendering

[my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OnEl7.png)

```
export const getServerSideProps: GetServerSideProps = async () => {
  const ref = collection(db, "books");
  const results = [];

  const unsub = onSnapshot(ref, (snapshot) => {
    snapshot.forEach((doc) => {
      results.push({ ...doc.data(), id: doc.id });
    });
    //here i get the results
    console.log(results)
  });

  // here is empty
  console.log(results)

  return {
    props: {
      books: results,
    },
  };
};
```

I'm trying to get the real time data from firestore database on the `getServerSideProps` function, inside the snapshot I can get the results, but when it's outside the array it's empty and I can't pass to props.

Comment: Maybe you can get some ideas from this answer.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/51794485/4652307

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using onSnapshot I would use getDocs (you need to import from 'firebase/firestore'):

```
export const getServerSideProps: GetServerSideProps = async () => {
    const [results, setResults] = useState([]);
    const ref = collection(db, 'books');
    const snapshot = await getDoc(docRef);
    articlesSnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
        setResults((oldArray) => [...oldArray, doc.data()]);
    });
    return {
        props: {
          books: results,
        },
    };
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I was also stucked in the same problem.
Here we should use get() instead of snapshot cause next will take care of your updated data under the hood.

so rewrite your code like this

```
export async function getServerSideProps(context) {
  const resultref = await db.collection("books").get();
  const results = resultRef.docs.map((doc)=>({
    id: doc.id,
    resultData: doc.data()
  }))
  return {
    props: { books:  JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(results)) },
  }
}
```

so map function will return the new array in variable results
which is then deep copied and passed as props

I hope this will give you the desired result